# Merging two sql databases (Datagridview)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have an existing sql database which has 2 columns of data (part and variant), another one of our systems uses sql in a different table in the same database but columns are (part and type), how would i merge the two in a datagridview (part, variant and type) using the part to do the select statement in a way to pull the other two bits of info and include them in the same datagridview. In vb.net

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are 2 entirely different things.  It doesnt sound like you want to "merge" at all, but simply JOIN 2 tables?

Comment: Yes, sorry i couldnt think of the word, but joining is what i want to achieve.

Comment: @PeterJames you should clear up your question to make it more clear. You also don't need the `visual-studio` tag. The question is not specifically about the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you would need an outer join to get the data, assuming there is an unique key and it's "part", for example:

```
Select part, variant, type 
from table1,table2 
where table1.part = table2.part;
```

Assuming that each table is unique and there is no relationship to part, nor a key:

```
Select part, variant
from table1
UNION ALL
select part, type
from table2;
```

This is ANSI SQL, so you may have to adapt it to SQL Server syntax, but I think the intent is clear.

Bind the resultset to the DataGridView.

Does this answer you question?

R/
Prescott ....